# Oracle query output to be comma-separated

Tags: sql, oracle, csv

I am writing a batch script for Oracle and want my output in a text file, columns separated by commas.

```
select 
quote_id ,
coverage_amount from Customer;
```

But it is coming as tab-delimited. How to get them separated by commas?

Comment: See my answer.  Note having things in columns seems to contradict as just csv perhaps unless you wanted lots of space separators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select 
quote_id || ', ' || coverage_amount 
from Customer;
```